# ajax get nested dict from django views.py. How can i access the nested data?

Tags: ajax, django

I use to ajax get nested dict from django views.py. How can i access the nested data?

In views.py

```
class Dash():
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = {'index':{'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,3]}, 'value':{'a':[2,3], 'b':[3,4]}}
        return Response(data)
```

In urls.py
`url(r'^api/chart/data/Dash$', Dash.as_view())`

In Dash.html

```
    var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/Dash'
    var index = []
    var value = []
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function (data) {
            index = data.index
            value = data.value
            setChart()
        },
        error: function (error_data) {
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })

    function setChart() {
        var rbline = echarts.init(document.getElementById('rb-line'));
        rbline.setOption({
            xAxis: [{
                type: 'category',
                data: index['a']
            }],
            series: [{
                name: 'data',
                type: 'line',
                data: value['a']
            }]
        });
    }
```

No chart shows. 
I am new to Jquery, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dump your data to json and you also need to specify the content type you are returning is json. javascript will do the rest for you.

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get(self, request, format=None):
    data = {'index': {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 3]}, 'value': {'a': [2, 3], 'b': [3, 4]}}
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json)
```

Then you can access it in your ajax:

```
success: function(data){
    var index = data.index;
    var value = data.value;
    var a = data.index['a']
}
```